# Non-Smooth Upscaling with graphics.DrawImage

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics

I am drawing some images in a grid. The images are saved as 16x16px pngs.

However, I later decided to up the size of the grid to 32x32px.

When I use the following code:

```
graphics.DrawImage(image, Xdraw, Ydraw, 32, 32);
```

where image is an Image loaded from a png, and Xdraw and Ydraw are the top left corner decided somewhere above.

The image is slightly blurry as .DrawImage uses bicubic(or some other smoothing function) to upscale the image. I would like it to turn the smoothing off, so I can preserve the hard edges.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using Winforms, WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: I am using winforms. The application is available for download at http://faskerstudio.com/minecraft/BBOB

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you should change `InterpolationMode` property of your graphics. Aslo take a look into `SmoothingMode` and `CompositingQuality` of Graphics class.

Comment: General hint for anyone trying to solve this problem in future: If you're using NearestNeighbor and your image is still blurred - make sure you are viewing it in 1:1 scale. Magnification in software you're using for the preview will most likely make it blurred (aliased).

Answer (score 3):

There's two things that might work.

- Try to experiment with the [InterpolationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.interpolationmode.aspx) property on your Graphics object. Unfortunately, off the top of my head, I don't know which setting woud work better than the default.
- Try using a [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx.aspx) on your Graphics object (an remember to reset it when you're done).

Comment: Damn, Anton beat me to the Interpolation mode ;-) Still, the ScaleTransform might work ...

Comment: You had the right answer, just late for the "accept", have an upvote cookie though.

Comment: Well, hadn't I inserted the links ... ;-) Anyway, thanks for the upvote. Depending on the output you're looking for, the ScaleTransform might work better than InterpolationMode, especially if you're looking at uneven scales like 2.3:1 instead of 2:1.

Comment: I will take that into consideration for future transforms.